# Packages as seen through yolk or pip

Tags: python, pip, pymssql, yolk

I need some help understanding how pip and yolk work

I ran `pip install pymssql`, which installed pymssql version `2.0.0b1-dev-20111019`, but then decided that I'd like to revert to an older version.

I ran `yolk -V pymssql` to check which versions I have available, but it only returns  `pymssql 1.0.2`. Shouldn't the version that I installed appear too?

Searching pypi through the website reveals that 1.0.2 is the only version available. Does this mean pip is using sources other than pypi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yolk` only search trough `PyPI` XMLRPC API as far as I know, while `pip` crawls the web looking for the "best" package that fits - the seed page is `http://pypi.python.org/simple/<PACKAGE_NAME>`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, look at the pip.log file to see where it's searching for packages.  I think yolk is just looking at what's registered on pypi, but pip is looking all over the place for the most up to date versions it can find.

Answer (score 1):

i'm usually running `pip` with the `-vv`-flag (double-verbose, or very verbose)...
in htis case that produces:

$ pip install -v -v --no-install pymssql

```
Downloading/unpacking pymssql
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql
  URLs to search for versions for pymssql:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/
  Getting page http://pymssql.sourceforge.net
  Getting page http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=40059&amp;package_id=32202
  Getting page http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/
  Getting page http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/downloads/list
  Analyzing links from page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/
   [... snip ...]
  Found link http://pymssql.googlecode.com/files/pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (from http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/), version: 2.0.0b1-dev-20111019
   [... snip ...]
  Using version 2.0.0b1-dev-20111019 (newest of versions: 2.0.0b1-dev-20111019, 2.0.0b1-dev-20111019, 1.0.2, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.0)
  Downloading pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (5.0Mb): 
  Downloading from URL http://pymssql.googlecode.com/files/pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (from http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/)
...Downloading pymssql-2.0.0b1-dev-20111019.tar.gz (5.0Mb): 5.0Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymssql
   [... snip ...]
```

this way you can clearly see where its downloading from.